# В чем отличие состояния приложения при его сворачивании в таск и при выключении экрана?

Tags: android, activity-life-cycle, таймер

Суть проблемы такова: В определенный момент времени генерируется звуковой сигнал и элемент активити подсвечивается другим цветом (setBackground...) и держит этот цвет несколько секунд. Если при открытом активити был просто выключен экран - то все правильно работает. Т.е. при включении экрана элемент все еще подсвечен и потом возвращается в исходное состояние. Если приложение было свернуто в таск, то после звукового сигнала открывая приложение, подсвечивание не происходило. Почему?

```
Подсвечивание делаю методом: 
private void setAlertColor(MyChronometer chronometer, int duration) {
        final MyChronometer chr = chronometer;
        final int delay = duration * 4000;
        chr.setBackgroundColor(alertColor);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler_interact.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        checkColor(chr);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, delay);
    }
```

Который находится:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ***

    chr.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            ***
            if (isMatch(acttime, intervalsTBshort)) {
            setAlertColor(actChr, shortSignal);
            ***
        }
    });
    chr.start();

    ***

}
```

Comment: покажите откуда вызывается setAlertColor и  MyChronometer это наследник View?

Comment: Добавил расположение.

Answer (score 1):

Если коротко:
При сворачивании вызывается сначала onPause(), затем onStop() 
При разворачивании вызывается onStart(), далее onResume()

А если вы отключаете экран, то активити уничтожается - помимо onPause() и onStop() вызывается ещё и onDestroy() 
при последующей активации экрана снова вызывается onCreate() и только потом onStart() и onResume().

Вывод: перенесите важный для вас код в соответствующий метод.

Comment: Не совсем так. Моя активити не уничтожается (не вызывается метод onDestroy/onCreate). В манифесте указаны параметры, которые восстанавливают уже созданную активность: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
android:launchMode="singleTop"